# Riverpod as global variable

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using riverpod in my project and I want to use is it provide instance of User class between widgets.

My UserState class:

```
import 'package:caralgo_mobile_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class UserState extends ChangeNotifier{
  User? _user;

  User? getUser(){
    return _user;
  }

  void setUser(User user){
    _user = user;
  }
}
```

Function where I'm writing to _user:

```
void logIn(){
    if(loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
      final _user = UserDraft(email: emailTEC.text, password: passwordTEC.text);
      _apiService.post('/signin', _user.toJson()).then((value) {
        scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value!.message)));
        ProviderContainer _container = ProviderContainer();
        _container.read(userProvider).setUser(User.fromJson(value.data['user']));
        _navigatorService.navigateToMainPage();
      }
      );
    }
  }
```

Class where I want to read User data:

```
class ConfigurationPageViewModel {
  final ApiService _apiService = GetIt.I.get<ApiService>();

  static final ProviderContainer _container = ProviderContainer();

  final registrationFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final validator = Validator();
  final emailTEC = TextEditingController(text: _container.read(userProvider).getUser()!.email);
  final nameTEC = TextEditingController(text: _container.read(userProvider).getUser()!.firstName);
  final familyNameTEC = TextEditingController(text: _container.read(userProvider).getUser()!.lastName);
  final passwordTEC = TextEditingController(text: _container.read(userProvider).getUser()!.password);
  var isEnterpriseUser = false;
  final enterpriseNameTEC = TextEditingController(text: _container.read(userProvider).getUser()!.enterprise);
}
```

I assumed this solution can work, instead it throws an error when I'm opening the ConfigurationPage:

> Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Are you doing this after the _user has been set or maybe before?

Comment: Sorry, I solved it already, just forgot to post an answer. Thanks for remainder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because of usage of ProviderContainer. In riverpod every provider has two objects: provider and state of provider. Providers itself are global, but states are container depending. In this case I couldn't access the User data, because each container that I used had separate state.
To solve this issue I got rid of ProviderContainers completely.
I'm passing userProvider directly from consumer widget to:

```
void logIn(dynamic userProvider){
    if(loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
      final _user = UserRegistrationInfo(email: emailTEC.text, password: passwordTEC.text);
      _apiService.post('/signin', _user.toJson()).then((value) {
        scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(value!.message)));
        userProvider.setUser(User.fromJson(value.data['user']));
        _navigatorService.navigateToMainPage();
      }
      );
    }
  }
```

And all the TextEditControllers are initialized inside the widget:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _configurationPageViewModel.emailTEC.text = ref.read(userProvider).getUser()!.email;
    _configurationPageViewModel.nameTEC.text = ref.read(userProvider).getUser()!.firstName;
    _configurationPageViewModel.familyNameTEC.text = ref.read(userProvider).getUser()!.lastName;
    _configurationPageViewModel.enterpriseCodeTEC.text = ref.read(userProvider).getUser()!.enterprise ?? '';
    _configurationPageViewModel.phoneNumberTEC.text = ref.read(userProvider).getUser()!.phone ?? '';
    super.initState();
  }
```